# Texting not working, Radioddity GD-77

Tags: dmr, brandmeister

I'm getting text message sending failed, from Radioddity GD77: "Message Sending Fail", on hotspot connected to 262993 as described here:

https://www.pe2kmv.nl/wp/en/dmr-en/sms-functions-via-dmr/

I haven't been able to text before although audio works.

In Brandmeister selfcare I have set to "Chinese radio".

Comment: If there is something necessary to this question in that link please include it in the body of the Question with an [edit]. A Question should be complete because internet links will last an Internet minute, making this Q&A less useful over time. Also, few people here will visit foreign links, so to atttract good Answers keep everything in the question.

Comment: I realize that your question is for people with particular experience, but as a courtesy to the rest of us, would you please [edit your post](https://ham.stackexchange.com/posts/20523/edit) and explain, in terms an average ham could understand, what it is that you're trying to do?  Also if you could give us more detail about your problem, that would surely help.  How exactly did you try to send a message?  Was there an error message?  Is there a log file that you could share?